# Add 2 Levels of "Content Approval" for a document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, content-approval

- I have document library which holds to levels of approval for a
  document
- And we all knew that Library Settings->Versioning Settings-> Require
  content approval for submitted items allows for "Approving or Rejecting"
  the document
- But I am seeking for 2 levels of approval for single document,Can any one help me how can I generate 2 levels of approval can be done in document library

Comment: Have you tried using an out-of-the-box approval workflow and configuring it for serial approval for two approvers?

Comment: I am not looking for manual Workflow,Because I user needs to enter the email address every time